# Reliable method to get signal strength on all devices?

Tags: android

[image: SignalStrength value retrieval through 2 different methods]

The image above shows the ASU % on a LTE connection, the orange line is from the values are retrieved from `TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` and the blue line is the value from the callback function [onSignalStrengthsChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength)). As can be seen on the chart the blue line indicates that the value of the `SignalStrengths` object does not change in line with the `getAllCellInfo` as is expected.

This means that `onSignalStrengthsChanged` cannot be relied upon to get a reliable signal value, where `getAllCellInfo` appears to have an accurate measurement. But, the problem is that `getAllCellInfo` doesn't work on all devices, a Huawei P9 will return a `null` value. Is there a better way to acquire **reliable** signal strength values on all devices?

To add to this, why are the 2 methods I already have respond with different values?

Comment: did u find the solution for this problem?

Comment: @TomásRodrigues I don't believe I found one

Comment: i could get the SignalStrenght on Huaweis via Java Reflection, if that helps u...

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getSignalStrengthByName(SignalStrength signalStrength, String methodName) {
  try {
    Class classFromName = Class.forName(SignalStrength.class.getName());
    java.lang.reflect.Method method = classFromName.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
    Object object = method.invoke(signalStrength);
    return (int) object;
    ....
```

I was able to retrieve several pieces of information for Huawei's instead of using the getAllCellInfo() method. I call the method like this:

```
getSignalStrengthByName(signalStrength, "getDbm");
getSignalStrengthByName(signalStrength, "getLteRsrp") //examples
```